# Reflow soldering with decreased footprint size fully within pad

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, footprint, pad, reflow

So the original footprint is first, followed is the edited footprint to allow for inner pads to be accessed.

[image]

As you will notice the extended pad footprint is smaller than the pad. Will this cause difficulties with reflow soldering? I'm assuming it won't because it's symmetrical and fully within the pad.

Anyone have issues doing this?

Comment: Like @tobalt noted there is a risk to get into trouble during soldering doing. Why do you need to do that? Avoid blind/plugged vias or their cost? To few layers available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thing to consider is: **How large is the pad on the component?**

If the component pad is big, then making the footprint pad small and running traces there will leave only the solder stop mask as an insulation. And solder mask is not considered a reliable insulation on long term and mass production scales.

Also, depending on how well the melting solder wets the component pad, it will pull it out of position, so the smaller balls might make a contact with the wrong pad.